# Не работает часть функции Ruby

Tags: ruby

Не пойму эту задачу.

Реализуйте функцию product(), которая сворачивает последовательность с помощью переданной функции. То есть вместо жестко заданной операции, например, сложения, нужно рекурсивно применять переданную функцию.

Примеры:

3 == product(1, 2, -> (first, second) { first + second }) # sum
6 == product(1, 3, -> (first, second) { first * second }) # multi

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта задача не сложная и главный смысл обучения в том, чтобы прийти к решению самому. Поэтому давайте я сперва попробую натолкнуть вас в правильном направлении и в конце сообщения, таки дам ответ, если самостоятельно не получится, то воспользуйтесь, но обязательно проанализируйте решение.

Итак, от вас требуется написать функцию, которая применяется сперва к первым двум элементам последовательности, затем к последнему результату выполнения функции и следующему элементу последовательности. Так можно написать, например, сумму всех элементов в массиве или, например, найти максимальный элемент массива (если переданная функция будет сравнивать два числа и возвращать наибольшее).
В Ruby уже есть метод, которые делает это за вас. И это reduce. Вы можете просто в правильном виде применить его, но интереснее будет написать product самому.
Попробуйте, например, с помощью цикла пройтись по всей коллекции, начиная со второго элемента. А первый элемент записать в переменную, в которой будет храниться результат на каждой итерации.

Судя по примерам, которые вы привели, вам нужно взять не коллекцию, а диапазон, ведь

```
sum 6 == product(1, 3, -> (first, second) { first * second }) # multi
```

будет справедливо только если ваша функция работает на 1, 2 и 3. (1*2*3 = 6).
Поэтому вот мое решение (версию без reduce, умение написать которую важно для обучения, я оставлю вам!):

```
def product(low, hig, f)
  (low..hig).reduce(&f)
end
```

Теперь вызов:

```
product(1, 3, ->(a, b) {a*b})
```

вернет ожидаемую 6.

Приятного обучения!